# What is the scalability of state of the art static binary analysis techniques?

Tags: static-analysis, binary-analysis

What is the largest program that has been analyzed by a semantics-based static binary analysis?

By semantics-based, I mean an analysis that examines the meaning of the program, and does not simply perform a computation on the syntax of the program, such as computing an `md5sum`.

Comment: Would you count the SAGE system from Microsoft? Also, someone should ask Veracode what the largest program they've analyzed is...

Comment: @Andrew As far as I know, SAGE is completely dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

The largest static analysis example I am aware of is 32,405 PPC instructions from [this paper](http://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/download/papers/binary_analysis/long-final-vmcai-11.pdf) on CFG recovery.  There is no analysis performed besides recovering the CFG.

Comment: Is decompilation considered a static analysis?  It should be, seeing as it does not execute the program.  And in which case, Hex-Rays does bigger jobs than that every day.

Comment: Also, in the deobfuscation example in my recent presentation [1], which is a static analysis, I have applied it to huge binaries on a very regular basis.  I think in order for this question or its answers to have any meaning, the term "static binary analysis" needs to be precisely defined.

Comment: @Syzygy Decompilation seems like fair game to me.  The link to your presentation does not seem to work, by the way.

Comment: Whoops ... that reference is [1] http://www.ruxconbreakpoint.com/assets/Uploads/bpx/semantics-based-methods-ruxcon.pdf ;-)

Comment: @Syzygy So how big is "huge"?

Comment: 1mb binaries, no problem. I've run it on larger (20-90mb) obfuscated binaries as well with some performance tweaking. You can probably tell in looking at the description of the algorithm that there's nothing inherently slow about it; it's about as fast as you might imagine that a static analysis could be. Hence my request for clarification of what we mean by "scalability of static binary analysis".